# How to pull token from wordpress url and give it a variable/value?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, variables, postback

Let me explain exactly what i'm trying to do.

1. Someone lands on https://crypto.enzlo.com and submits their email. They get taken to the thank you page.
2. The thank you page url contains a bunch of tokens that looks like this:
   https://crypto.enzlo.com/apply/?contactId=103&inf_contact_key=d5e172efa53b9940a898afcfa25596e21f32e5a885a1411d8c094e77aedca3ba&inf_field_BrowserLanguage=en-US%2Cen%3Bq%3D0.9&inf_field_FirstName=&inf_field_Email=heiko%40viceoffers.com&inf_4dAXudNU8407Jeuy=
3. I need to pull the 'inf_field_Email' token from the url and put it into a image tracking url that needs to fire so I can track the signup and the email. The image iframe pixel i need to fire on this thank you page looks like this:

4. you'll notice "track_id=inf_field_Email" in the iframe url. I need track_id to post the email back to me. So the variable/token inf_field_Email should be showing the email address from the thank you page url. So in this case the inf_field_Email would be heiko@viceoffers.com

I am thinking I will need to concatenate it into the url using JS, by giving it a variable/value. But not sure how to do that or how to then put that variable into the iframe image pixel that needs to fire on the same page...
Please let me know what you guys think is the best approach for this. I have been able to post the inf_field_Email as text on a page and have it display the email using a wordpress plugin but that plugin couldn't transfer that token into the iframe url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to convert the URL into an object so we can call the properties. We can do accomplish this by using JSON.parse, and then concatenating the property to the iframe src, below is an example of what I would do.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var search = location.search.substring(1);
    search = JSON.parse('{"' + search.replace(/&/g, '","').replace(/=/g,'":"') + '"}', function(key, value) { return key===""?value:decodeURIComponent(value) });

    console.log(search.inf_field_Email);

    document.getElementById("govice").src = "https://govice.online/track/goal-iframe?goal_id=466&track_id=inf_field_Email=" + search.inf_field_Email;
});
```